# Finding an element from a drop-down menu

Tags: perl, selenium

This is concerning WWW::Selenium module from Perl's CPAN. I'm having an issue finding `BigBroLot1446130409` in the HTML below. It is a drop down menu.

Here is the HTML

```
<select name="lot_id" id="lot_id" title="">
<option value="">Select an Available Lot</option>


<option value="497">
  BigBroLot1446130409
  - 0g
  (100 credits to list)
</option>

<option value="500">
  BigBroLot1446133752
  - 199g
  (100 credits to list)
</option>
```

When I use this code, it actutally works.

```
$locator = q{//select[@id="lot_id" and @name="lot_id"]};
$ret = $sel->wait_for_element_present($locator, $timeout);
$ret = $sel->select($locator, "value=497");
```

The code above works but in actual testing but I need to find the element based on text `BigBroLot1446130409` and not on `value=497`.

```
<option value="497">
  BigBroLot1446130409
  - 0g
  (100 credits to list)
</option>
```

It is a drop-down menu so I think I need to use the following function from the documentation:

```
$sel->select($select_locator, $option_locator)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ikegami I won't be using regular expression, I have reworded the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As stated previously, I want to select from a drop-down menu based on the 'BigBroLotXXXXXX'name which is from a variable. In the module's documentation there is a function called

```
$sel->get_select_options($select_locator)

Gets all option labels in the specified select drop-down.
$select_locator is an element locator identifying a drop-down menu
Returns an array of all option labels in the specified select drop-down.
```

So, I was able to know that all my choices from the drop-down menu was in an array.

The function to select an element from a drop-down menu is:

```
$sel->select($select_locator, $option_locator)
```

The documentation for this module states that $option_locator can be:

```
label=labelPattern:matches options based on their labels

label=regexp:^[Oo]ther

value=valuePattern:matches options based on their values.

id=id:matches options based on their ids.

index=index:matches an option based on its index (offset from zero).
```

First, I need to define the locator of where my array of choices are so I can feed it into the `get_select_options` function:

```
$locator = q{//select[@id="lot_id" and @name="lot_id"]};

my @array = $sel->get_select_options($locator);
```

For grins, I wanted to verify that @array did have choices in them:

```
Select an Available Lot
BigBroLot1446130409 - 0g (100 credits to list)
BigBroLot1446087714 - 0g (100 credits to list)
BigBroLot1446665592 - 36g (100 credits to list)
BigBroLot1446060974 - 0g (100 credits to list)
BigBroLot1446668987 - 64g (100 credits to list)
```

As stated in the `$sel-select` function, I can find elements using indexes so I used that as my option_locator for the `$sel->select` function with the help of the `List::MoreUtils` module. For example lets say `$xyz = BigBroLot1446130409`

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(first_index);
use 5.010;
my ($index) = grep { $array[$_] =~ /$xyz/ } (0 .. @array-1);
```

And here is the code that selected my element from a drop-down menu:

```
$locator = q{//select[@id="lot_id" and @name="lot_id"]};
$ret = $sel->select($locator,"index=$index");
```